# How to aggregate event for denormalization?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, aggregation

A user clickstream is represented by events with type and event_timestamp properties. For example:

```
userid  type        event_timestamp (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS)
01      install     2018-01-01T00:00:00.000
01      level_up    2018-01-15T00:00:00.000
01      new_item    2018-02-03T00:00:00.000
```

All input data are stored in partition of `event_timestamp` field, e.g. into `2018-01-01`, `2018-01-02`... its folders.

For do denormalization there has been a hackle (hive) like this (just an idea, syntax is not checked):

```
select userid,
    MIN(install_date),
    MIN(level_up_date),
    MIN(new_item_date)
from (
    select
        userid,
        CASE when type = 'install' then event_timestamp else null as install_date,
        CASE when type = 'level_up' then event_timestamp else null as level_up_date,
        CASE when type = 'new_item' then event_timestamp else null as new_item_date
        from event_table
) group by userid;
```

When this performed onto all data everything works. But what about partitioning?

When the input data is split by `event_timestamp` and the processing is performed onto new arrived data only (e.g. input partitions are processed separately) - instead of 1 row I got 3 (in different partitions of course):

```
userid  install_date  level_up_date new_item_date
 01      2018-01-01        null        null
 01      null           2018-01-15
 01      null              null     2018-02-03
```

Instead of:

```
userid  install_date  level_up_date new_item_date
  01      2018-01-01    2018-01-15   2018-02-03
```

Note that time gap between the dates is unlimited - a user sends `install` even this year and `level_up` next year.
Is there any common way to solve this? Theoretically, I can stay with storing different events into different partitions and perform select userid, MIN (install_date), MIN (level_up_date), MIN (new_item_date) from processed_data` on entire processed data set.

But this is full data set scan.

Answer (score 0):

This is called conditional aggregation. The following would work.

```
select userid,
MIN(CASE when type = 'install' then event_timestamp END) as install_date,
MIN(CASE when type = 'level_up' then event_timestamp END) as level_up_date,
MIN(CASE when type = 'new_item' then event_timestamp END) as new_item_date
from event_table
group by userid
```

Comment: Thanks for naming. But what about partitioning? This requires full data scan. Can conditional aggregation be implemented to process data incrementally?

Comment: use a `where` clause to filter for rows in a specific time period.